# Xamarin iOS Back To Master Button Is not shown on detail view

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In short I have a SplitViewController as RootController.
And in constructor I've added master and detail controllers.
Detail Controller is wrapped into Navigation Controller.

```
        {
        _masterViewController = new MenuViewController();
        _inventories = new InventoriesViewController();

        _detailNavigationController = new UINavigationController(_inventories);

        ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {
            _masterViewController,
            _detailNavigationController
        };
```

What are the ways I can show the Menu (show master) back button on details Navigation Bar?

We don't use storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found the property on the UISplitViewController

```
DisplayModeButtonItem
```

So after creation of master and detail controller (detail controller is wrapped into UINavigationController) I added the DisplayModeButtonItem into NavigationBar LeftItem of detailed controller. It gave me the desired look and behaviour

```
{
        _masterViewController = new MenuViewController();

        _inventories = new InventoriesViewController();
        _inventoriesNavigation = new UINavigationController(_inventories);

        _inventories.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = DisplayModeButtonItem;

        ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {
            _masterViewController,
            _inventoriesNavigation
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following code in the method ViewDidLoad()

```
        UIButton backButton = new UIButton();
        backButton.Frame = new CGRect(0,0,20,20);
        backButton.SetTitle("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
        backButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Gray, UIControlState.Normal);
        backButton.SetImage(new UIImage("back"), UIControlState.Normal);
        //backButton.SetImage(new UIImage("001.jpg"), UIControlState.Normal);
        backButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
        {

            NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
        };
        UIBarButtonItem backItem = new UIBarButtonItem(backButton);

        NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = backItem;
```

Comment: I assume it is supposed to go to the detail controller that is wrapped in NavigationController. But there is nothing to Pop. And button is disabled.

Comment: SplitViewController has a property DisplayModeButtonItem. In SplitViewController after
        _inventories = new InventoriesViewController();

        _detailNavigationController = new UINavigationController(_inventories);
I inserted the 
            _inventories.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = DisplayModeButtonItem;

And it shows me the back button with disered behaviour